# Replace URL segment hyphens with spaces using htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a friendly URL as follows:

```
www.dominio.com.br/cidade/sao-paulo
```

And here's my htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cidade/(.*)$ busca-cidade.php?cidade=$1
```

And the SQL query:

```
Select * from cidades where cidade = 'sao-paulo'
```

Is it possible to replace the hyphens with spaces using htaccess and rewrite rules? So the friendly URL will be mapped to:

```
www.dominio.com.br/busca-cidade.php?cidade=sao%20paulo
```

This finished my code, was great, would give to optimize.

```
####################################TESTE
RewriteRule ^teste?$ busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L
#(1) http://www.imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste 

#GET TIPO IMOVEL
RewriteRule ^(teste/[^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^teste/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)?$ /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=$1&tipo_mae=$2&tipo_imovel=$3 [L,QSA]
#(4) imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao

#GETREFERENCIA
RewriteRule ^(teste/[^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^teste/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)?$ /tudo-imovel.php?codigo=$5 [L,QSA]
#(6) imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu/16538

#GET BAIRRO
RewriteRule ^(teste/[^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)([^\-]*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^teste/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)?$ /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=$1&tipo_mae=$2&tipo_imovel=$3&bairro=$4 [L,QSA]
#(5) imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu

#GET TIPO MAE
RewriteRule ^(teste/[^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)([^\-]*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^teste/([^\-]*)/([^\-]*)?$ /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=$1&tipo_mae=$2 [L,QSA]
#(3) imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos

#GET CIDADE LOCAÇÃO
RewriteRule ^(teste/[^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^teste/([^\-]+)$ /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=$1 [L,QSA]
#(2) imobiliariaemaximovel.com.br/teste/Sorocaba
```

Semantic order, however, in my htaccess it is confusing, but works rsrs

```
#(1) /teste 
#(2) /teste/Sorocaba
#(3) /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos
#(4) /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao
#(5) /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu
#(6) /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu/16538
```

Comment: You will find better results here http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Internal rewrite to recursively replace hyphens with
    # spaces, only on URIs that start with `/cidade`.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cidade
    RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]

    # Now rewrite requests to the php file if only there's
    # no hyphen in the request segment after `cidade/`.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
    RewriteRule ^cidade/(.+)$ /busca-cidade.php?cidade=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It maps:

```bsh
www.dominio.com.br/cidade/sao-paulo
```

To:

```bsh
www.dominio.com.br/busca-cidade.php?cidade=sao%20paulo
```

Replacing **all** the hyphens with space characters.

---

#### Update 1

In case you need to rewrite another segment as well, you just need to match that segment in the last `RewriteRule`. The first one replaces hyphen characters throughout the whole request URI.

```bsh
RewriteRule ^cidade/(.+)/(.+)$ /busca-cidade.php?cidade=$1&bairro=$2 [L]
```

---

#### Update 2

Regarding the [latest update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41427077/revisions) to your question, I must say that there's a slightly better and cleaner way to achieve the same effect.

As far as I see, except that one rewrite rule which maps a request to `tudo-imovel.php` file, all other requests are being mapped to `busca-cidade.php`. You can combine all the conditions and achieve the same only by 2 rewrite rules, not 6.

However, there might be a slight side-effect to this approach, though; It always sets all the query string params (`locacao_venda`, `cidade`, `tipo_mae`, etc.), even though some might be empty. That's due to the combination of multiple rules together.

But, as far as I see, there's no serious issue with this. The only thing that you need to take care of is to use `empty()` on your `$_GET` variables (instead of checking whether it's set or not using `isset()`).

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/teste
    RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)[\-]+(.*)$ $1\ $2 [DPI]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
    RewriteRule ^teste/(.+/){4}(\d+) /tudo-imovel.php?codigo=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
    RewriteRule ^teste/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?$ /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=$1&tipo_mae=$2&tipo_imovel=$3&bairro=$4 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=&(.*)
</IfModule>

## Results:
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste
# To:
#    /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=&tipo_mae=&tipo_imovel=&bairro=
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste/Sorocaba
# To:
#    /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=Sorocaba&tipo_mae=&tipo_imovel=&bairro=
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos
# To:
#    /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=Sorocaba&tipo_mae=Apartamentos&tipo_imovel=&bairro=
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao
# To:
#    /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=Sorocaba&tipo_mae=Apartamentos&tipo_imovel=Apto%20Padrao&bairro=
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu
# To:
#    /busca-cidade.php?locacao_venda=L&cidade=Sorocaba&tipo_mae=Apartamentos&tipo_imovel=Apto%20Padrao&bairro=Jardim%20Pacaembu
#
# Maps this:
#    /teste/Sorocaba/Apartamentos/Apto-Padrao/Jardim-Pacaembu/16538
# To:
#    /tudo-imovel.php?codigo=16538
#
```

You see that I only used one rewrite rule to replace those hyphens. You were repeating it for each of your rewrite rules. It's unecessary, as it recursively replaces all of the hyphens and then goes to other rewrite rules. See those `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-` as guards until all hyphens are replaced.

Not sure if there's an easy way to drop empty query string params. Since you're not utilizing the `R` flag and all these happens under the hood, there's nothing annoying about it.

Comment: Not correct, this code replace

RewriteRule ^cidade/([^\-]+)$ /busca-cidade.php?cidade=$1 [L]
to  
RewriteRule ^cidade/([^\-]+)$ /busca cidade.php?cidade=$1 [L]

Return not fund

I like this only path cidade no everone domain

Regards

Comment: Try it now; I added an extra condition to only apply the rules on URIs starting with `/cidade`. And please bear in mind that the `DPI` flag is available in Apache version **2.2.12 and later**.

Comment: One more problem, so, with city without hyphens ex: cidade/orlando, fail.
Kurole

Comment: Look at my changes

Comment: @kurole: Well done! It's fine as long as it works for you. However, I updated the answer with a better solution, in case that you want a slightly cleaner solution to all those rewrites.

Comment: After a long time without problems, my url gives a 500 error.

see the link
Http://www.grupokaza.com.br/alugar/Sao-Jose-dos-Campos/Apartamento/Padrao/Conjunto-Residencial-Trinta-e-Um-de-Marco/16230

When you have more than 8 hyphen, error 500 is displayed, try removing a hyphen, it will work, or try to replace by the underline, it will work.

Do you have any idea what it might be?
thank you