# Want to rewrite url using htaccess with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The challenge is I need to pass parameter received in the URL

```
Https://mydomin.com/asdfg/website/view.php?v=qwertyuiop
```

To

```
Https://mydomin.com/asdfg/website/view/qwertyuiop
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace URL segment hyphens with spaces using htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427077/replace-url-segment-hyphens-with-spaces-using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: @Aakash
Try this link. May this link help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427077/replace-url-segment-hyphens-with-spaces-using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: @Aakash Mishra, could you please check my answer once if this has helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/([\w-]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1.php?v=%2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

OR to check if `view.php` is present in local path you could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/([\w-]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1.php?v=%2 [NC,L,QSA]
```